# Sunspider failed to find a shell

Tags: javascript, v8

SVN checkout from 'http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/SunSpider/'
V8 Shell directory: ~/v8/shell

command line:

perl sunspider --shell=~/v8/shell

It doesn't work and show me 'Failed to open ....js at sunspider line 124'.

but I think my path is correct , just tell my why, TKS!

Answer (score 0):

I tried and the '~' makes it fails for me too.
Try with a full or relative path:
chmod +x sunspider
./sunspider --shell=/home/username/v8/shell --args=--expose_gc

Don't forget the --expose_gc argument for the v8 shell. Otherwise it will not work, as the Sunspider benchmarks do a garbage collection between each benchmark, and v8 does not expose GC functions by default.

edit: typo...